# Oracle SQL splitting a string with repeated delimiters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a loop that is going through an array where each value needs to be split on a forward slash (`/`). I have a code that works fine but if a string has more than one forward slash, my code creates 3 substrings instead of 2:

```
xxx/xx/x
```

becomes

```
xxx
xx
x
```

and I need

```
xxx
xx/x
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(arr(i),'[^/]+', 1, level) BULK COLLECT 
    INTO sub_array
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(arr(i), '[^/]+', 1, level)
    IS NOT NULL;
```

Can anyone help?

I tried changing the occurence paramter to `1' but it did not make any difference:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(arr(i),'[^/]+', 1, 1) BULK COLLECT 
    INTO sub_array
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(arr(i), '[^/]+', 1, 1)
    IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: still getting the same error:( perhaps it has to do more with the REGEX_SUBSTR than with the actual expression?

Comment: You may get these chunks with two expressions:  `regexp_substr(col, '^[^/]*')` and `regexp_substr(col, '/(.*)', 1,1,NULL,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need any regular expressions if you only want to split on the first `/`. You can use `INSTR` to find the position of the first `/` character easily, then use `SUBSTR` to split at that position.

```
WITH test_input AS (
    SELECT 'xxx/xx/x' AS val
    FROM dual
)

SELECT t.val                                AS original_string,
       INSTR(t.val,'/',1)                   AS position_of_first_slash,
       SUBSTR(t.val,0,INSTR(t.val,'/',1)-1) AS substring_before_first_slash,
       SUBSTR(t.val,INSTR(t.val,'/',1)+1)   AS substring_after_first_slash
FROM test_input t
```